# How to fully utilize the debug features?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to ask if anyone know how to make use of the debug features to actually retrieve certain data. Cos currently, I am stuck in a bind where in the debug mode I see my .tag value on a variable but failed to obtain in. Even after all the casting and all. Is there any tutorials where it teaches how to look and use a debugger?

Sorry I dont think I can show you what I am doing or refering to. I hope you can visualize what I am trying to say.

Comment: You can show the local variable or scope variable on the debugger window (CMD+SHIFT+R). ANd you can select different scope from the "Thread" panel. But it is better to have the code which you want to loo at in order we can help.

Comment: yeap, I am at that part. And I know how to navigate around it. When you mouse over a class. It will show a list of the variables or classes right? Then I have to look for variable value?

Comment: You have a list of variables that are in scope in the upper-right, too. If you're trying to find out what the value is of something more complex you can use (typing at the GDB prompt) "po objectname" if it's an object or "print variableName" if it's an int or double or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [Apple's XCode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html). It's actually quite helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I got pretty much 'gave up' with my work and trying to look deeper into the Debugger Guide and now I am working another way around it. But thanks for the link. I Will look into it.